# How to trigger a jquery plugin after a keyup event from an inline script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/8jdfJ/1/) you can see the script I am working on that uses this [plugin](http://preview.benmartinstudios.com.au/jquery-price-calculator-pro/js/jquery-price-calculator-pro.js) to create estimates. However, this plugin only allows predetermined values in data-attributes to be used in checkbox and radiobutton inputs. However, I need to be able to enter values for what I want to use it for, so I created a field that uses keyup to change the data-attribute named `data-cost`. This method does update the data-attributes, but does not trigger the script to sum the new values entered.

I wanted to know if there was a edit the plugin or trigger it outside the script when they keyup event happens.

This is the keyup script

```
$(function () {
    $('#account_balance1').on('keyup blur paste', function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            var str = $(self).val();
            $("input[data-cost][debt]").attr('data-cost',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
            $("input[data-cost][debt]").attr('debt',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
            calculateTotalFor() // this is how I do it on inline scripts
        }, 0)
    })     
});
```

This is the input that has the data-attribute changed from the keyup event.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="100" debt="" value="" name="f_2[]"/>
```

This is the input where the value is entered for the keyup event

```
<input type="text" maxlength="7" class="balance" id="account_balance1" name="cardbalance" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking the plugin source, this solves your problem:

```
$("input[data-cost][debt]").data('cost',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
$("input[data-cost][debt]").data('debt',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
$('#jquery-order-form').data('jprice').onChange();
```

The problem is that you updated the html attributes, but not the inner data.

Here you have it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/8jdfJ/3/

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: Hey Edgar, I added the new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066740/jquery-calculation-script-not-working-after-i-modified-it if you have a chance to look at it.

Comment: Hey Michael, I was about to answer but someone already did :)

Comment: I have one more question, but I already hit my limit today. But if you had a minute to look at it, I will vote up enough of your answers to equal 100 points :)  Here is a fiddle of it. http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/JgY2t/8/

Comment: The problem is the inputs you dynamically add do not calculate in the totals.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm solving it, give me a minute :)

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia Done. Just changed line 39 of the fiddle, updates here: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/JgY2t/12/

Comment: I guess I hit the limit on what I can vote one person up in a day. because it won't let me give you higher than 10981. It was almost 10 points, but I will give you more tomorrow

Comment: Thanks! According to SO (that uses GMT+0 time), it's a new day since 2 minutes ago, could you try again please? :D

Comment: ya it worked, I got you up to a 1166, but then it stopped again giving points after that, but it still gives you an up vote

Comment: That is about 150 points total I gave, that is a lot of quesitons :)