# Jquery calculation script not working after I modified it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a Jquery plugin that sums up values that are entered into data attributes named `data-cost` when you select the checkboxes or radio buttons. I modified the script so you could enter values into a `text input`

So for example, the script is triggered when a user enters the value of the text input with as seen below.

```
<input type="text" class="balance" id="account_balance1" name="cardbalance" value=""/>
```

It changes the data attribute in this input

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="100" debt="" value="" name="f_2[]"/>
```

But after adding 9 additional instances of the `checkbox input` and the `text input`, it does not sum up the 10 instances in the blue total box to the right as seen in this fiddle. When you first load the fiddle you will notice it sums $1000 until the changes are made. After that it just changes the value to whatever you type and it adds a zero to the right of the value you enter.

Here you can see a working example with my modifications.  http://preview.benmartinstudios.com.au/jquery-price-calculator-pro/quantities.html

This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/8jdfJ/11/

Comment: If you type in '-30' it says that you're going to pay *me?...*

Comment: did you mean to add a link to the fiddle? w/o looking at the fiddle, i'm going to guess that there is an problem in type-casting when getting the aggregate sum, meaning that you're appending "0" and not adding (int) 0

Comment: @ManofSnow Is that a joke?

Comment: @awei its at the bottom of the quesiton. I did forget the first time but I edited within a minute.   http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/8jdfJ/11/

Comment: @OP: ok, looking now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the value of an input is changed, I think you just want the `data-` attributes on the associated checkbox updated. You are updating the values on all the checkboxes.

Like this:

```
$('.balance').on('keyup blur paste', function() {
    var $self = $(this),
        $checkbox = $self.closest('li').find('input:checkbox');
    setTimeout(function() {
        var str = $self.val();
        $checkbox.data('cost',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
        $checkbox.data('debt',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
        calculateTotalFor();
    }, 0)
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5mfP/)

Comment: Yes the `data-cost` attribute is what plugin uses to uses to sum the list. They are currently being changed, I verified it with Chrome Inspect Element tool

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should add event delegation like so:

```
 $('.well').on('keyup blur paste', '.balance', function() {
               var self = $(this);
           setTimeout(function() {
               var str = $(self).val();
               $("input[data-cost][debt]").data('cost',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
               $("input[data-cost][debt]").data('debt',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
               calculateTotalFor();
           }, 0)
});
```